# Length of ray from interior point to surface of sphere

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If we have a sphere centered at the origin with radius $R$, and interior point $p=(x,y,z)$, how do we find the length of a ray that is cast from point $p$ to the surface of the sphere in direction $[\theta, \phi]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we obtain a direction vector $\mathbf{U}$ from the two given angles $(\theta, \phi)$. If these are conventional polar angles (bearing and azimuth), then
$$
\mathbf{U} = (\cos\phi\cos\theta, \cos\phi\sin\theta, \sin\phi)
$$
Then, if the ray passes through the point $\mathbf{P}$ and is in the direction of the vector $\mathbf{U}$, its parametric equation can be written
$$
\mathbf{X}(t) = \mathbf{P} + t \mathbf{U}
$$
If a point $\mathbf{X}$ lies on your sphere, then 
$$
\mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{X} = R^2
$$
If you substitute $\mathbf{X}(t)$ from the first equation into the second, you'll get a quadratic equation that you can solve to get values of $t$. In fact, since $\mathbf{U}$ has unit length, the quadratic simplifies a bit. You get:
$$
t^2 + + 2(\mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{U})t + \mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{P} - R^2 = 0
$$

If the point $\mathbf{P}$ is inside the sphere, this quadratic will have two real roots, one positive and one negative. You want the one that's positive. This $t$ value is the distance from $\mathbf{P}$ to the intersection point.

Comment: Thank you! Does anything change if the sphere has an arbitrary origin?

Comment: Yes. If the sphere center is at the point $\mathbf{Q}$, then the equation of the sphere becomes $ (\mathbf{X}   - \mathbf{Q}) \cdot  (\mathbf{X}   - \mathbf{Q}) = R^2$, instead of just $ \mathbf{X}  \cdot  \mathbf{X}  = R^2$

Comment: Alternatively, you can just move everything (sphere and ray) so that the sphere center is relocated to the origin.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: How do we obtain the direction vector $U$? Is it through applying rotation matrices?